# Moderator Pro-Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion, moderation

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community's issues are properly addressed.

[image: JohnP]
[image: slugster]
[image: stslavik]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections after your site makes it through graduation.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It's a learning experience for everyone.

---

Let's also thank these users for having previously stepped up and helped moderate this community:

[image: Matt Chan]
[image: David H. Clements]
[image: stslavik]

Answer (score 5):

I, for one, welcome our new moderator overlords...

Comment: I have a feeling I've just been called a robot...

Comment: @stslavik: You are aware of the Simpson episode where that quote comes from right?

Comment: It's the one with Homer in space eating potato chips, right? The reporter says something like, "And I for one welcome our new insect overlords" or something... I'm still getting caught up on some 15 years worth of Simpsons back episodes...

Comment: @stslavik: that is correct. ^_~

Answer (score 2):

Happy to be on board. :)

[Go ninja, go ninja, go!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vx7dt0Wscpc)

Answer (score 1):

^_^ Congrats! I would have been glad to serve, but I'm happy for those picked too.